# What are some scenarios in which you'd care the direction of a browser selection?

Tags: javascript, dom, browser, selection, textselection

The browser DOM Selection API provides properties showing what node and offset a selection begins at (`Selection.anchorNode` and `Selection.anchorOffset`), and what node and offset the selection ends at (`Selection.focusNode` and `Selection.focusOffset`). In some of my selection handling methods, I need to normalize these values to a consistent direction. It got me wondering, in what situations would the direction of a selection matter? It's not for handling RTL languages; users arbitrarily select in either direction in any language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the [question](https://discuss.prosemirror.net/t/basic-question-what-is-purpose-of-anchor-and-head/1309/2) on the ProseMirror support board.There are common behaviors that make use of the directionality of a DOM selection:

- **Shift-click**, which uses the anchor end of a selection to determine (when a user clicks outside of an existing selection) how the selection should be extended;
- **Shift-arrow**, which uses the  anchor end similarly to shift-click but with arrow keys instead of a mouse click to determine how the selection should be extended.
- Displaying a tooltip at the location closest to the user’s mouse after a selection.